# What does 飄過 mean in this context?

Tags: translation, mandarin, word, traditional-characters, writing

Was playing some game that usually has a decent amount of Chinese speakers and at the beginning of the match somebody spammed this:

[image]

What would 飄過 mean here? I know it can mean to float but otherwise I am lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually in your context, the 飘过 is not it's official meaning. It's a kind of Network language. you can treat "飘过" here as "I'm just a passerby. What's going on right now has nothing to do with me." with a funny, humorous emotion.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense now